# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

Im using the embedded **Maven** with **Eclipse** and whenever I try to create a new Maven project I keep getting the same error. I have looked everywhere on internet and cant seem to find a solution.

This is the error I get whenever I try to create a new Maven project:

```
> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I have read somewhere that its probably because of the network Im working from and I have to configure a proxy, but I dont use a proxy to connect to the internet. I think I should also note that Im using a **Virtual Machine** with Windows 7, with the settings on bridged network.

This is what my **pom.xml** contain after I create the Maven project with the error from above:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>proyecto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>base</name>
</project>
```

This is my settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies> 
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>

</settings>
```

**EDIT**
I have read similar problems and tried to follow those steps to solve them, however none have worked. Im using a clean installation of Eclipse Mars with the embedded Maven. I also have a clean installation of JBoss set up. Im not using a proxy, I only have a Virtual Machine where I installed Eclipse and the other things I mentioned.

**EDIT**

I fixed it :D, all I did was delete my eclipse folder, delete the workspace, delete the .m2 folder, installed back everything (unzipped eclipse, installed jboss, unzipped and installed my wildfly). However my .m2 folder doesn't have the settings.xml? and I dont know how its fixed.

Comment: Yeah none of those things worked for me

Comment: if you dont have a proxy, why do you have it configured in your settings.xml? just try to remove it

Comment: I added it because I didn't know what else to do because it wasn't working.  But Ill remove it, and see whats happens when I try other things to fix it.

Comment: First test is to check if your build works on command line...if it's working than import it into Eclipse...

Comment: How do I do that? sorry but im kinda nub :D

Comment: its fixed thanks for any help